# Displaying degrees of freedom in stargazer table

Tags: r, stargazer

When constructing documents with `Sweave` and R, I make use of the `stargazer` library for tables.

When using `stargazer`, is there a mechanism to display the degrees of freedom associated with the residual deviance for a model constructed with `glm`?

Minimal code:

```
library(stargazer)
set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(x=1:10)
data$y <- data$x + rnorm(10, 0, 0.2)
model <- glm(y~x, data=data, family=gaussian)
summary(model)
stargazer(model,title="A test", align=T,label="Tab:test",style="all2")
```

Resultant stargazer table will have Observations, Log Likelihood, AIC, Residual Deviance and Null Deviance but no d.f. I can work out d.f. but would have thought this could be displayed directly. Also see:

https://sites.google.com/site/marekhlavac/stargazer

Update #1:

Thank you Marek for your response. For the benefit of others that encounter this, here is the process that lets you form the work around:

1. Obtain version 4.0 (not 4.5 - I'll come back to this) from http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/stargazer/
2. Within the package directory structure under R, edit "stargazer-internal.R" as per the instructions in the answer below.
3. Ensure that the library is not loaded in your R session
4. Ensure that you have removed any existing stargazer lib
5. Install the edited version of the stargazer package.
6. Reload the library in R and compile as per usual.

Here are the commands:

```
detach("package:stargazer", unload=TRUE)
remove.packages("stargazer")
```

From the command line:

```
R CMD INSTALL -l <path to library directory> stargazer
```

Finally (assuming you have a few models at hand),

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(model6,model7,model8, title="Logistic model summary",align=T,label="Tab:logmod1",  font.size="footnotesize", style="all2")
```

Result:

```
% Table created by stargazer v.4.0 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: Tue, Sep 24, 2013 - 17:17:17
% Requires LaTeX packages: dcolumn 
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Logistic model summary} 
  \label{Tab:logmod1} 
\footnotesize 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-4} 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{3}{c}{whalesighted} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{logistic}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{probit}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{glm: binomial}} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{link = cloglog}} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 visibility & 0.392^{***} & 0.226^{***} & 0.216^{***} \\ 
  & (0.051) & (0.027) & (0.026) \\ 
  Constant & -1.251^{***} & -0.745^{***} & -1.149^{***} \\ 
  & (0.246) & (0.144) & (0.182) \\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{232} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{232} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{232} \\ 
Log Likelihood & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-110.485} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-110.888} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-112.694} \\ 
Akaike Inf. Crit. & \multicolumn{1}{c}{224.970} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{225.775} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{229.388} \\ 
Residual Deviance (df = 230) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{220.970} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{221.775} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{225.388} \\ 
Null Deviance (df = 231) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{310.759} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{310.759} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{310.759} \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{3}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\normalsize 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Returning to the error I get when I implement the workaround based on the 4.5 code. I actually get the same error when I install from the mac binary (version 4.5.1) (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/index.html) and simply try to use stargazer, see below.

```
> install.packages("stargazer")
trying URL 'http://cran.ms.unimelb.edu.au/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0/stargazer_4.5.1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-tar' length 332917 bytes (325 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 325 Kb

> stargazer(model6,model7,model8,      
+           title="Logistic model summary",
+           align=T,
+           label="Tab:logmod1", 
+           font.size="footnotesize",
+           style="all2")
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "visibility") : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

Marek, for your reference I will email the results traceback() to you.
Cheers.

Comment: I'm not a user of `stargazer`, but I will often "take a shot" at a problem if there is minimal code offered.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed follow-up. I will examine your issue, and - if necessary - fix in the next release. Note that, without implementing the workaround, 4.5.1 works without any difficulty (just does not default to degrees of freedom output for null and residual deviance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stargazer author here. It looks like the package's default is not to output degrees of freedom for residual and null deviance. I will consider changing the default in a future release.

As a quick fix for now, you might wish to use the source package (from CRAN), and modify the function .adjust.settings.style in stargazer-internal.R to contain the following:

```
   if (style == "all") {
      .format.table.parts <<- c("=!","dependent variable label","dependent variables","models","columns","numbers","-","coefficients","-","omit","-","additional","N","R-squared","adjusted R-squared","max R-squared","log likelihood","sigma2","theta(se)*(p)", "SER(df)","F statistic(df)*(p)","chi2(df)*(p)","Wald(df)*(p)","LR(df)*(p)","logrank(df)*(p)","AIC","BIC","UBRE","rho(se)*(p)","Mills(se)*(p)","residual deviance(df)*","null deviance(df)*","=!","notes")  
      .format.coefficient.table.parts <<- c("variable name","coefficient*","standard error","t-stat","p-value")  
    }

    else if (style == "all2") {
      .format.table.parts <<- c("=!","dependent variable label","dependent variables","models","columns","numbers","-","coefficients","-","omit","-","additional","N","R-squared","adjusted R-squared","max R-squared","log likelihood","sigma2","theta(se)*(p)", "SER(df)","F statistic(df)*(p)","chi2(df)*(p)","Wald(df)*(p)","LR(df)*(p)","logrank(df)*(p)","AIC","BIC","UBRE","rho(se)*(p)","Mills(se)*(p)","residual deviance(df)*","null deviance(df)*","=!","notes")  
      .format.coefficient.table.parts <<- c("variable name","coefficient*","standard error")  
    }
```

Note that the only change here is that I added "(df)*" to "residual deviance" and "null deviance".